# PhoneGap + MongoLab security

Tags: rest, angularjs, cordova, security, mlab

I'm thinking of using AngularJS + PhoneGap + MongoLab. I'm using the example found [here](http://angularjs.org/#mongolab-js) under "Wire up a Backend".

How does the security work ? I'm seeing "apiKey" hardcoded. Is it possible for a user to easily reverse engineer the app and pull out the apiKey ? What are the best practices to secure your access to MongoLab data when you use it with Phone Gap ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't protect the api-key client-side, [see this Q&A](https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20269612-REST-api-permissions-and-security-best-practice).

MongoLab suggest that you proxy the connections behind a server under your control, but it quite defeats the "all-cloud" purpose since you end up again with a single point of failure for your app.